# Non-breaking space without quotation mark in the batch file FOR in (string) script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file and expect to output three lines of string sentences to a txt file, just like this:

```
powershell "Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online"
complete
123456
```

however, the first sentence: powershell "Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online" contains a space that breaks the string in ouput file, like this:

```
powershell 
"Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online"
complete
123456
```

And I don't hope to have quotation mark "" on the first sentence in the output file because I need it can be executed as a powershell command, any experts can kindly give a help on this and advise. Thanks a lot

My batch code:

```
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (
powershell "Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online"
complete
123456
) do echo %%A>> D:\BatOutput.txt
```

Comment: I suggest simply `echo`ing the three lines and redirecting them to a text file to avoid using a `for` loop altogether. You can even use a set of parentheses around the set of `echo`s so that you only have to `>D:\BatOutput.txt` once.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks for your advise, at the beginning, I used echo each sentence in the script, only three lines strings are OK for that, but if you have over 10 or 20 lines of strings to output, that may be a inefficacy, so that I changed to use the FOR loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in (^"
powershell "Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online"^

complete^

123456
^") do echo %%A>> D:\BatOutput.txt
```

Just change the `FOR` by `FOR /F "delims="`, terminate each line with a caret `^` character and insert a blank line between lines...

Although a simpler solution would be to store the desired lines *in a file* and just copy or type/append the file

Comment: Thanks a lot, awesome,  and i just changed it a little bit, because your sample output the first line with a space ahead, 
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in (^"powershell "Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online"^

complete^

123456
^") do echo %%A>> D:\BatOutput.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 for %%A in (
  "powershell #Get-appxprovisionedpackage -Online#"
  complete
  123456
 ) do SET "line=%%~A"&ECHO !line:#="!
)>filename
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's *a* way to do it - but I prefer Mofi's method.

Simply replace each `"` with an otherwise-unused character. Quote any string containing spaces. Assign the value in `%%A` to a user-variable `line`, using `%%~A` to remove enclosing quotes. Then `echo` the result in `line`, substituting `"` for `#`.

Enclosing the code in a pair of parentheses forms a code block which allows the output to be redirected to the file.  That way, the output file is opened once; using `>` to start, then `>>` to append is ugly and repeatedly opens/closes the file.

See `for /?` and `set /?` from the prompt for documentation - or browse through thousands of examples on SO

Comment: Thanks Magoo, your sample output all those three line into on line, but anyway, thank you all the same